# Algorithm to determine how much and in what direction two rectangles are overlapping?

Tags: java, algorithm, collision-detection

Does anyone know of an algorithm that can be used to determine how much and in what direction two rectangles are overlapping? I have spent hours trying to figure this out so I can implement it into a basic tile game written in slick2d + java.

Comment: What does "in what direction" mean? Could you give some examples?

Comment: @Vlad By direction I mean which side of the rectangle is overlapping.

Comment: Have a look at this question (and the linked js code): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99565/simplest-way-to-calculate-the-intersect-area-of-two-rectangles

Comment: side? you mean the sides of the rectangles are parallel to the axes?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yes. All of the rectangles have no rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Poll the coordinates for the corners, and if `Square1` has any corner between `Square2`'s nearest and farthest vertices, they are in collision by the difference in coordinates?

Example:

```
square1.setVertex1(0,0);
square1.setVertex2(2,0);
square1.setVertex3(2,2);
square1.setVertex4(0,2);

square2.setVertex1(1,1);
square2.setVertex2(4,1);
square2.setVertex3(4,4);
square2.setVertex4(1,4);

Vertex[] verticesSq1=Square1.getVertices();
for (Vertex vert: verticesSq1) {
    if(vert.getXVal>square2.getLowestXVal() &&
       vert.getXVal<square2.getHighestXVal() 

       &&
       vert.getYval>square2.getLowestYval() &&
       vert.getYVal<square2.getHighestYVal() {

            System.out.write("Vertex "+vert.ID+" is overlapping Square 2 by " +
            vert.getXval()-square2.getLowestXVal +","+
            vert.getYval()-square2.getLowestYVal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us represent each rectangle as R=(x1,x2,y1,y2) (i.e. (x1,y1), (x1,y2), (x2,y1), (x2,y2) are vertices of that rectangle, and x1

Now, we have two rectangles R1 and R2 and we want to know if they overlap and if yes, what direction.

For each vertex of R1 check if it is inside rectangle R2 which you can represent as 4 bits. The mapping is very direct:

```
0000 -> None (or R2 is inside R1)
0001 -> R2 is bottom right of R1
0010 -> R2 is top right of R1
0100 -> R2 is bottom left of R1
1000 -> R2 is top left of R1
0011 -> R2 is right of R1
0101 -> R2 is bottom of R1
1100 -> R2 is left of R1
1010 -> R2 is left of R1
1111 -> R1 is inside R2
```

Other combinations are impossible.

Answer (score 0):

First make a **center** point between rectangles ( center of second rectangle - center of first one).
Check distance form every point of each rectangle to **center point**.
Pick 2 closest points, check if one of them is inside other rectangle, if yes, the  rectangle created by these two point gives us the overlapping area.